# Measure area polygon and distance with google map

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

i have an issue with the passage of value with a maps.
The code create a polygon, and measure the area (in mq), and the distance (in mt).
And, in html i would what when the user draw the polygon, the code will give in output both area and distance.
This code allows to the user of choice if to see measure of area or the distance.
javascript:

```
function on_click_function(location_passed){
click_polygon.setMap(null);                             //  clears click_polygon from map
click_line.setMap(null);                                //  clears click_line from map
points_array.push(location_passed);             
    //  push clicked lat lng into points array
if (document.getElementById("polygon_mode").checked){   //  create (or recreate) the click_polygon object
    create_polygon();
    click_polygon.setMap(my_map);
}
if (document.getElementById("line_mode").checked){      //  create or recreate the click_line
    create_line();
    click_line.setMap(my_map);
}
clear_markers();
rewrite_markers();
calculate_dimensions_and_display();
}// end on_click_function
```

and in html code:

```
<table id = "output_table">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="draw_mode" id = "line_mode" onclick = "mode_was_changed();" checked = "checked"/> Ora seleziona i vertici del tetto
                </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="draw_mode" id = "polygon_mode" onclick = "mode_was_changed();"  /> <!-- checked = "checked" --> Calcola l'area del tuo tetto
                </td>

                <td>Dimensioni: <span id="area">&nbsp;</span>
                </td>
                <td>Area: <span id="area">&nbsp;</span>
                </td>
```

How can i to solve this issue?

Best Regards

Alessandro

Comment: You should simplify the examples to just contain a defined structure of your points and how you want the output; I feel this is way too much to be able to give a sensible answer. Also, do you want to handle all types of polygons (doing area calculations for self intersecting polygons are harder than non-intersecting, etc.)?

Comment: serve only the calculation of a polygon, the url is this: http://app.tettosano.com/php_test/calculator.php#   I state that the application is used to calculate the area and perimeter of a roof at a time, so from here we will only calculate a roof, then a polygon.
the user will seek its roof, it will calculate the area and perimeter also immediately.

Comment: This pastebin: http://pastebin.com/XWu8VgkQ   are calculate_dimensions_and_display, now this code Displays area or perimeter, but my issue are for displays area AND perimeter.